# Reset iPad Mini v1 Not Validating

Tags: ipad, restart

I have an iPad Mini v1 that had a memory leak.  So I backed it up, and reset the unit.

Upon restart, it asks me some basic setup questions, and a WiFi network to join.  Accomplished.  The WiFi channel works.

It asks me to enter my Apple ID and password, and it spins.  Then this:

**Verification Failed
There was an error connecting to the Apple ID server.**

I can't get past this, so the unit is stuck.  There is nothing in the Finder (Ventura) that allows me to do anything, and I can't into the iPad to reset the unit once again.

Anybody know how I can get this to work properly?  I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to partially restore, then erase again.  Then it came back.

Finicky.

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it answers your problem as you said. It avoids it being bumped by Community bot as unsolved.